# Page scroll disappear when jquery dialog closes

Tags: jquery, css

My code before closing the dialog...

```
 $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
 $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('width','100%');
 $('#content').removeClass('lightbox_bg');
 $('#saveDialog').dialog('close');
```

My CSS...

```
<style>
.lightbox_bg {
    background:rgb(153,153,153) none repeat scroll 0 0; 
    left:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:50;        
    position:fixed;
}
.modal{
    position:absolute;       
    z-index:51;        
}
```

When the dialog opens the scroll stays, but when it closes scroll disappears keeping the page in the same position. Any ideas.Thanks.

Comment: Hi there. what are u talking about? we are not in your mind. some explanation of what you are using and what you are gonna do

Comment: Sorry, my apologies if the provided information does not seem to be sufficient. I am using Jquery 1.4 here. My sceen has two separate jsps(left and right). So, when the right half reloads, I am presented with a scroll but when a Jquery dialog appears and goes away, the scroll also disappears from the right jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the suggestion. Got the solution by just manually adding:

```
$("body").css("overflow","scroll");
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes because you have this line

```
 $('body').css('overflow','hidden'); // Setting overflow hidden on body and thus removing the scroll bar
```

Remove this line and it will bring your scroll back.

Comment: Sorry but I had tried that out already. The issue remains the same.

Comment: Can you post a live link of your page?